# ¿Cómo hace un map a jsonArray en React?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, reactjs, api

Estoy tratando de mostrar el siguiente JsonArray en una tabla usando react, pero no tengo muy claro como puedo acceder a los elementos que están dentro del JsonArray de **empresas**, **Bodega_Origen** y **Bodega_Destino**.

```
      {
        "Estado": 1,
        "_id": "5e31ecf510ec6117387548a1",
        "usuarios": "5e262750803c451ca4a27c36",
        "empresas": {
            "_id": "5e2f4c3ef80d8246f0e545d8",
            "Nombre_Empresa": "ING. Y HER. S.A."
        },
        "Tipo_Documento": "AF",
        "Numero_Documento": "1",
        "Bodega_Origen": {
            "_id": "5e2619ccbb29d71aa8455cad",
            "Descripcion": "BODEGA PRINCIPAL"
        },
        "Bodega_Destino": {
            "_id": "5e2629f110b9f32d10524ca5",
            "Descripcion": "BODEGA Obra parma"
        },
        "Responsable": "Mauricio",
        "Estado_Documento": "PR",
        "Observaciones": "",
        "Detalles": [],
        "Fecha_Creacion": "2020-01-29T20:37:09.919Z"
    }
```

El siguiente es el método que estoy usando para obtener los datos y parsearlos. En este momento está recorriendo los datos correctamente, pero no muestra los datos que están dentro de la **Bodega_Origen** y la **Bodega_Destino**.

```
    loadData(){
        var cont = 0;
        console.log('Getting list');
        const activeTab = this.state.activeTab;
        const ids = this.ids;
        const path = activeTab===0?'/empresa/list':'/articulo/list';
        console.log(this.state.listQuery);
        cont++;
        console.log(cont)
        return this.Requests.list(path, this.state.listQuery).then(response=>{
            if(response && response.length !== 0){// El request no ha devuelto un arreglo vacio
                let dt = response;
                dt.map((el,i)=>{
                    let filterProperties = [];//Propiedades de interes
                    filterProperties[i] = {};//Inicializar el objeto para cada elemento del arreglo
                    ids[activeTab].forEach(key=>{
                        if(el[key]._id){
                            el[key] = el[key].nombre;
                        }
                        filterProperties[i][key] = el[key];
                    })
                    return filterProperties;
                });
                console.log(dt);
                let stateData = this.state.data.slice();
                stateData[activeTab] = dt.slice();
                this.setState({data:stateData});
            }else{
                let stateData = this.state.data.slice();
                stateData[activeTab] = [];
                this.setState({data:stateData})
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Como recibes el **JSONArray** y como lo conviertes ? para mostrarlo ?

Comment: en este fragmento de codigo `'Bodega_Origen][0].Descripcion'` te falta un llave para cerrar y en este otro no tienes las llaves `'Bodega_Destino[0].Descripcion'`, ademas si pones [0] estas accediendo a id y no a descripcion

Answer (score 0):

lo que ocurre es que `.map` te devuelve una lista aparate `var ls = lista.map(...);` si ya tienes una tabla donde mostrar seria mejor que armes un modelo solo con eso datos de tu tabla

```
        if(response && response.length !== 0){// El request no ha devuelto un arreglo vacio
            let dt = response;
            var lista = dt.map((el,i)=>{
                // el : objeto , i : indice
                var data = {
                    Estado:el.Estado,
                    usuarios:el.usuarios,
                    empresas:el.empresas.Nombre_Empresa,
                    Bodega_Origen:el.Bodega_Origen.Descripcion,
                    Bodega_Destino:el.Bodega_Destino.Descripcion,
                }
                //puedes seguir agregando mas
                return data;
            }
            console.log(lista);
            // return lista;
        }else{
            let stateData = this.state.data.slice();
            stateData[activeTab] = [];
            this.setState({data:stateData})
        }
```